# URL Encoding - Chinese Charcters

Tags: php, html, encoding, character-encoding, urlencode

When i paste 圆通速递 into a website and check the POST using FIREBUG ,it gave me the following

```
%D4%B2%CD%A8%CB%D9%B5%DD
```

申通E物流 is becomeing 鐢抽€欵鐗╂祦 after i URL encode and the website decodes it obviously  urlencode($trackingname); didn't work out well :(

**How do i encode my Chinese character to that same format** as the website is doing?My chinese character is stored in mysql. I tried decoding using some format but cant return it to that Chinese character pasted.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: http://php.net/urlencode

Comment: http://www.functions-online.com/urlencode.html I tried the text online , it isnt returning the same as what firebug is showing when submitted on the asp.net website

Comment: It depends on the encoding of the Chinese characters. Where do they come from, are they UTF-8?

Comment: The URL-encoding shown in the question is for GB2312, according to python-chardet.

Comment: @sourcejedi Yes i just tested it , it is GB2312 , Thank you. I will test the encoding soon, should work out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Your website must use UTF-8. In HTML5 that would be (HTML):

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

When you connect to your Database, be sure to use (PHP):

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

Finally, your table definition that stores Chinese characters must also have UTF-8 collation (SQL):

```
`column name` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8
```